# Missing DLL's after compiling with gfortran compiler

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I have some code in Fortran that I would like to compile with GFortran. For this I use Code :: Block with the GFortran compiler (*"The codeblocks-16.01mingw_fortran-setup.exe file includes additionally to the GFortran compiler (TDM-GCC)"*).
After the compilation, the .exe file can not be opened on the same computer because the following libraries are missing:

- libgfortran-3.dll
- libquadmath-0.dll
- libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll

After the libraries have been copied to the folder, it still does not work.

Why is it like this and how can you create a working .exe with gfortran?

P.S. ifort makes his work flawless.

Comment: For ifort, you must run a setup script (e.g. by clicking on Start menu) which sets up PATH et al.  to include the folder with the support .dll.  You could make a .bat file which does the equivalent for your TDM installation.  Utilities such as dumpbin /dependents or dependency walker can help diagnose whether you got it right.  You can't expect Windows to be as easy as linux.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Is there no way to handle everything necessary in the IDE (in my case Code :: Blocks)?

Comment: Instead of "debug" try "release".